# Rotate MainCamera by z-angle after using an item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to undertand Unity4 and having some troubles. The idea of my 3d game is to collect some mushrooms and to it them. One of the possible effects is changing up and down. So would positions of earth and sky exchange. I've tryed to do it with camera rotation. But i suppose that i am doing it wrong.

```
override public void Use(){
    this.activated = true;
}

override public void Update(){
    base.Update ();
    if (this.activated) {       
        Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 180);
    }
}
```

After using a mushroom the main camera starts jumping and rotating some crazy angles in a very short time. But it should stay stable and change it self correct to player inputs.

What are my mistakes and what can I do differently? Thanks for attention.

The answer of user1711383 helped but not perfectly.

Did'not explaiden the whole situtation. It works only in inventory. After I push 'I' the inversion disappears. I used

```
public bool visible=false;
public GUISkin skin;
public MouseLook player;
public MouseLook cam;

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.I)) {
        visible=!visible;
        player.enabled = !visible;
        cam.enabled = !visible;
    }

}

void OnGUI(){
    if (visible) {
        GUI.skin = skin;
        GUI.Window(0,new Rect((Screen.width-1024)/2,0,1024,600),InventoryBody,"Inventory");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to rotate will continue to happen unless you set activated to be false again.

```
override public void Update(){
    base.Update ();
    if (this.activated) {       
        Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 180);
        this.activated = false;
    }
}
```

Consider using Vector3.Lerp() for smooth movement between two states.
There is a video tutorial that includes it.
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth/camera-movement